# Remote install MSI package not working when logged off

Tags: powershell, remote-access, windows-server, windows-installer, invoke-command

I've got a problem with my script I'm working on. One part of this script should remotely install a MSI package. The problem is that it only works while I'm logged in to the target servers.

Here's the code I'm using:

**1st try:**

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    cd "C:\FlexAgent"
    Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i 'FlexNet Inventory Agent.msi'  /qn /l newlogfile.txt"
}
```

**2nd try:**

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    cd "C:\FlexAgent"
    Invoke-Expression "msiexec /i 'FlexNet Inventory Agent.msi' /qn /l logfile.txt"
}
```

**3rd try:**

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    cd "C:\FlexAgent\"
    & msiexec /i 'FlexNet Inventory Agent.msi' /qn '/l*v' 'logfile.txt'
}
```

**Folder: FlexAgent:**

```
    Directory: \\RemoteComputer\c$\FlexAgent


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                           
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                           
d----        03.08.2018     09:47            ManageSoft upgrade agent                                                                                       
-a---        08.08.2017     12:34   15203756 Data1.cab                                                                                                      
-a---        08.08.2017     12:34    3089408 FlexNet Inventory Agent.msi                                                                                    
-a---        03.08.2018     11:26          2 logfile.txt                                                                                                    
-a---        29.05.2018     09:41       6985 mgssetup.ini                                                                                                   
-a---        08.08.2017     12:34    1308656 setup.exe                                                                                                      
-a---        08.08.2017     12:34       5350 Setup.ini
```

I wasn't able to find any further information in the log files I defined or the logfiles in the event viewer.
The logfiles are being created but they are empty.

Is there a way to install this MSI package unattended without the need to be logged in?

---

**More Infos:**

- Target Servers: Windows Server 2008 - 2016
- Script Server:  Windows Server 2012 R2
- Domain:         Yes, they are all in the same domain.
- User:           Logged in with a Domain Admin
- Network:        All in the same network
- Firewall:

  - TCP/5985 not blocked (used for remote PowerShell)
  - TCP/5986 not blocked (used for remote PowerShell)

Comment: Try `& msiexec /i 'FlexNet Inventory Agent.msi' '/qn' '/l*v' 'logfile.txt'` instead of `Start-Process` or `Invoke-Expression`. Does `logfile.txt` show anything?

Comment: We appreciate that you're trying to be courteous, but we prefer to focus on the problem at hand, so please don't add fluff like "thanks in advance" to your questions.

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work either. The logfile "logfile.txt" is empty but it was created while I was logged off.

Comment: Does the MSI file exist in `C:\FlexAgent` on the remote computer?

Comment: Yes it exists. I added a list into my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. I was able to install the MSI package remotely with the following commands:

```
$product= [WMICLASS]"\\$RemoteComputer\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_Product"
$product.Install("C:\FlexAgent\FlexNet Inventory Agent.msi")
```

It worked even when logged off.